How to activate default Workspace in Adobe Premier Pro 2023?
I was following a tutorial on Youtube on how to render videos using Adobe Premier Pro 2023 like this one.

I tried to follow the instruction on how to create workspace but mine is so different than in the Youtube that I don't know how to have the same Workspace as the one show in the video.

My question is, how to have the same workspace as shown in the Youtube? Is it really the default workspace of Adobe Premier Pro 2023 when first rendering a video?
Thanks!
